# Spring Security Every URL is a blank page

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need your help.
I am trying to write a web application with Spring Security. I am using Tomcat 7.0.56 to run it.
But when I add to web.xml these lines:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Every URL in this application is shown as blank page.

Here is spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

       <http auto-config="true">
              <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
       </http>

       <authentication-manager>
              <authentication-provider>
                     <user-service>
                            <user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                     </user-service>
              </authentication-provider>
       </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
       <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

       <bean
               class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="prefix">
                     <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
              </property>
              <property name="suffix">
                     <value>.jsp</value>
              </property>
       </bean>

</beans>
```

This happens with every web application with Spring Security, that I write, even if I just follow the instructions in tutorial.

I can not understand what is wrong. If you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: set the log level of spring security to debug an have a look at the log. perhaps this will help you

Comment: thank you! The problem was in my schema declarations in spring-security.xml